# How to send audio from ios and store in mysql using php?

Tags: php, ios

I have to send a audio file from and iOS app and store in MySQL using php.  I have converted the audio file to base64string and sent to the server.  The problem is I can store only few bytes of data in the database.

```
NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"audiostring=%@,",audioStr];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(!connection){
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
}
```

```php
if($_POST["audiostring"])
{
    $sql="insert into AudioDetails (audiostring)values('$_POST[audiostring]')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Above are the code for iOS and php.

Comment: If storing the file in the database is not a requirement, I suggest that you think about storing the file in the file system, which is a better approach, since its a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store the base64 string in the database, simply decode the string and create a physical file in your filesystem, then put the reference to this file in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the http body using post method. and use ASIFormDataRequest framework for sending data to php server.

```
asirequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]; 
[asirequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];  
[asirequest setPostValue:appDelegate.loggedInUserInfo.userID forKey:@"iSenderID"];                   
[asirequest setPostValue:@"0" forKey:@"iReceiverID"];
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.wav"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];

[asirequest setData:[imageData copy] withFileName:@"Sound.wav" andContentType:@"Audio/mp3" forKey:@"vSoundName"];

[asirequest startAsynchronous];
```